# Comparing two points corresponding to two different normal distributions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, hypothesis-testing

I have two multi variate normal distributions N1 and N2.
Say two points p1 is from N1 and p2 is from N2.
I want to get some statistical features from these two points. How can I do it?

I need a richer representation (not one number). Say my points are in a d dimensional space, in that case I need a d dimensional vector which represents the statistical difference between these two points.

Comment: What do you mean by "statistical features"?

Comment: Hi I have modified the question. please have a look.

Comment: Do you know the parameters of $N_1$ and $N_2$ or not?

Comment: Ya I know about the two distributions N1 and N2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each point is completely described by a d-length vector. The difference between them is another d-dimensional vector, but the distance can be calculated in various ways, e.g. Euclidean, Mahalnobis.